# How to dynamically create / destroy JS variables and append / remove their values in a string

Tags: javascript

I want to create javascript variables on the fly and append their values into a string. I actually am unable to find a method which dynamically declares variables in javascript. Once that is done I would want to do the reverse of this. So my question has two parts : one is related to creating and deleting variables on the fly as per requirement and the other is related to appending or deleting those variables value into a string at a specific point in the string.

Comment: What you want to do can probably be done with an array or object. Just add an item/property to the array/object. How to delete them has already been asked here. If you'd provide more information about what you actually want to achieve, we could help you better.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `eval` function.
**But!** you should ask yourself twice why do you need to *"create variables on the fly"*

[eval on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're after correctly, you should use an object for this:

```
var o = {};
o.name = "value"; // Creating a property
delete o.name;    // Deleting a property
```

It sounds like you have a specific problem, could you perhaps share a bit more information about your problem?

Comment: Uhm. *"You can use the `delete` operator to delete variables declared implicitly but not those declared with the `var` or the `function` statement."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete